# App crashes while using ImageDecoder#createSource(contentResolver, uri)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

Trying to replace the deprecated code for retrieving images from Uri

> MediaStore#Images#Media#getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)

with the new

> ImageDecoder#createSource(contentResolver, uri)

Here is my new Code:

```
Bitmap thumbNail;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                            thumbNail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    getContentResolver(),
                                    data.getData()
                            );
                        } else {
                            ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                            thumbNail = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
                        }
```

But I noticed that anytime I tried using it to process an image of a relatively large size of about 2MB to 3.5MB. The app crashes which message

> Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Could I be doing something wrong or is it not suitable for handling larger image files? The app works fine when I resolve to use the deprecated method:

> MediaStore#Images#Media#getBitmap(contentResolver, uri).

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

because it will throw OOM for some devices,
to solve this, you can set sampleSize when decode using ImageDecoder

```
val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, imageUri)
val listener = ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener { decoder, info, source ->
    var scaleFactor = (info.size.width / 1280).coerceAtMost(info.size.height / 1280)
    if (scaleFactor < 1) scaleFactor = 1
    decoder.setTargetSampleSize(scaleFactor)
    decoder.setOnPartialImageListener {
        true
    }
}
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder#setTargetSampleSize(int)